# Python has 2 paths in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, path, double

I have uninstalled a couple of installations of Python from my Windows 10 machine, but when I try to run pip from the command prompt now, using the only python install that is specified in PATH in the System Environment Variables, it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\programs files\python37\python.exe" "<other correct path that exists and is in the PATH variable>pip.exe"
```

This is happening regardless of whether I specify a package to install or not. I think there is some confusion over this old python37 install which no longer exists. Where can I find and remove any reference to this path which does not exist on disk?

Thank you,

Adnan

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `Python` from your computer, then removing variables from `PATH` manually via **System Properties** > **Advanced** > **Environment Variables** ([this](http://johnatten.com/2014/12/07/adding-and-editing-path-environment-variables-in-windows/) link can help how to find it). Also, remember that

> (...) there are two sections, User Variables for Current User, and System Variables.

Delete Python references from both sections, then reinstall the version of Python that you need, with `Add Python 3.x to PATH` option checked.